# pandas preserve multi index multi columns with to and from csv

Tags: python, pandas

How to easily recover a multi-indexed mutli-columns indexed with dump into a csv file?

MWE:

```
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'a': list(range(10)),
        'b': list(range(10)),
        'c': list(range(10)),
        'd': list(range(10)),
        'score': pd.np.random.rand(10),
    })
    .pivot_table(
        index=['a', 'b'],
        columns=['c', 'd'],
        values='score',
    )
)

df.to_csv('pivot_table.csv')

# pd.read_csv('pivot_table.csv')
```

I don't know how to recover the initial `df` with `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: try with to_excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.read_csv("'pivot_table.csv'", header = [0,1], index_col = [0,1])
```

You have to specify the header and index col rows/columns. In our case it would be the 0,1 row of the csv, and the 0,1 column.